# Symfony2: (Sub-)Category Custom Field Type

Tags: forms, symfony, categories

I have some issues creating a custom field type.

What I have is an Entity:

```
Category  
Id | Name | parent_id
```

And what I want in the end is a select-Field that looks like this:

```
Category 1
- SubCategory 1
- SubCategory 2
Category 2
- Subcategory 3
- SubCategory 4
Category 3
Category 4
```

So my approach was to create an entity field that returns a function from CategoryRepository. Like this:

```
$builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => "AcmeAppBundle:Category",
                "property" => "Name",
                 'query_builder' => function (\path\to\CategoryRepository $repository)
                 {
                     return $repository->getOrderedCategories();
                 }
                )
```

And the Repository contains:

```
class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
 public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM AcmeAppBundle:Category u WHERE u.parent is NULL ORDER BY u.priority DESC')
        ->getResult();
}

public function getOrderedCategories()
{
   //get the Parent-"Nodes"
   $entity = $this->getCategories();
   $arr = array();

    foreach ($entity as $cat) {  

        $arr[]=$cat;  

        foreach ($cat->getChildren() as $child)
        { 
           $arr[] = $child;
        }
    }
}
```

My current Error-Message is:

```
Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given
```

Is this a good approach? Is there a better one?

EDIT:
On request: The Category-Entity

```
/**
* Category
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\AppBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
*/
class Category
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Priority", type="integer", nullable=true)
 * 
 */
private $priority;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Phrase", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $phrases;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
 **/
protected $children;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $parent;

public function __construct() {
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->children;
}

public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

public function setParent($parent)
{
    if($parent -> getParent() == NULL)
    {
            $this->parent = $parent;
    }  
}

 public function getPhrases()
{
    return $this->phrases;
}
...some Setters&Getters
```

Comment: please review my answer and ask if anything unclear/missing otherwise please accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'query_builder' option in the entity field type has to **return a QueryBuilder** instance instead of the $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult(). (which is an array in your case)

```
'query_builder' => function (\path\to\CategoryRepository $repository)
{
    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('category')
        ->where('category.parent is null')
        ->leftJoin('category.children', 'child', 'WITH', 'child.parent = category')
        ->orderBy('category.priority', 'DESC');
 }
```

trying to implement a tree structure for your categories? Give Gedmo's [Tree](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) extension a shot :)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your fast reply. Though it's not exactly what I was looking for. 1st the leftJoin doesn't work - I only get the parent entities (i mapped the children with an arraycollection - could that be the problem?) and 2nd: i would like to format the choices as described above which I cannot do with just that one Query, can I?  I'm gonna try out the TreeExtension. Thank you, nifr!

Comment: can you please provide you category entity class so - without it can't help you or suggest a better implementation. if my answer helped you please accept or at least upvote it ;)

Comment: I am very thankful for your help and I assure you, you will get your upvote as soon as I have the rep to do so ;) I simply don't want to accept the answer already. maybe some other answers come in. Category-Entity is at the end of the question now.